# where in the uk may i find a register or map of properties and their energy use

Tags: data-request, government, uk, energy

I am looking for a register of the energy use of buildings in the uk with granularity down to individual building. Is this publicly available? I recall that this information is collected when processing energy certificates.

I may have found a source here which appears to be  a private company presenting information which is collected on the demand of the government and paid for by the owners of the property.

https://www.epcregister.com

Are there other datasets?

Comment: Did you look on data.gov.uk?  For example this record seems to suggest that the data isn't publicly available: http://data.gov.uk/dataset/domestic-energy-performance-certificate-register

Comment: Energy use of individual buildings in the UK is largely covered by the Data Protection Act, and getting hold of it is very difficult. Some academic departments have managed it for specific research projects.  EPCs don't give you real energy use: they give you an estimated rating based on a model grounded in dodgy assumptions, and fed with unreliable inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer, but you could try to extrapolate the data using [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org). As far as I know, the data contains also information about the usage of the building (housing, industrial). Based on the size and the usage you could estimate the energy use of the building. How it is done for the heat demand is described e.g. in this [IEEE paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSG.2013.2295856).

Answer (score 2):

The UK Energy Research Center publishes a number of datasets relating to energy use in public buildings:

http://ukedc.rl.ac.uk/cgi-bin/edc_search.pl?GoButton=Browse

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago DECC (now BEIS) published anonymised data on annual electricity/gas consumption in 4 million UK homes. There's a sample here, with the link to the main host at the bottom of the page:

https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/national-energy-efficiency-data-framework-need-anonymised-data-2014

You won't be able to link it to an address or anything, however will hopefully help anyway!